# I cannot display my response in text widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have used post method for user login which is successfully done and it returns responses in list which I need to display in text widget in some other class, but when I try to display it in text widget using Future builder it throws exception in my emulator but nothing shows in my console.

This is my APIService class, it works fine when I post details but when i try to display the response in text widget, it shows exception from this class, at the bottom of this code there is **" throw Exception('Failed');"** it shows this exception only when I try to display the response in text widgets.

```
class APIService {
  Future<DoctorResponseLoginModels> register(
      DoctorRequestLoginModels doctorLoginRequestModels) async {

    String url = "http://202.51.75.142:9028/api/PatientMaster/PostPatientLogin";

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var globalToken = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
    print("$globalToken");

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $globalToken',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(doctorLoginRequestModels));

    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    DoctorResponseLoginModels responseModel =
        DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(responseJson);

    print("This is ${response.body}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      sharedPreferences.setInt('code', response.statusCode);
      var StatusCode = sharedPreferences.getInt('code');
      print("This contains : $StatusCode");


      return DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }

}
```

**This is My DoctorRequestLoginModels class which I send to server.**

```
DoctorRequestLoginModels doctorRequestLoginModelsFromJson(String str) =>
    DoctorRequestLoginModels.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String doctorRequestLoginModelsToJson(DoctorRequestLoginModels data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class DoctorRequestLoginModels {
  DoctorRequestLoginModels({
    required this.code,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  String code;
  String username;
  String password;

  factory DoctorRequestLoginModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      DoctorRequestLoginModels(
        code: json["code"],
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      };
}
```

**This is my DoctorRespinseModels class which I need to display in text widgets.**

```
DoctorResponseLoginModels doctorResponseLoginModelsFromJson(String str) =>
    DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String doctorResponseLoginModelsToJson(DoctorResponseLoginModels data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class DoctorResponseLoginModels {
  DoctorResponseLoginModels({
    this.doctorId,
    this.nmCno,
    this.doctorName,
    this.contactNo,
    this.username,
    this.emailId,
    this.strEmail,
    this.id,
    this.intMobile,
    this.gender,
    this.currentAddress,
    this.depId,
    this.entryDate,
    this.password,
    this.code,
    this.isActive,
    this.hospitalName,
    this.department,
    this.deviceId,
    this.profile,
    this.token,
    this.role,
  });

  int? doctorId;
  String? nmCno;
  String? doctorName;
  String? contactNo;
  dynamic? username;
  String? emailId;
  String? strEmail;
  int? id;
  String? intMobile;
  dynamic? gender;
  String? currentAddress;
  int? depId;
  String? entryDate;
  dynamic? password;
  dynamic? code;
  bool? isActive;
  dynamic? hospitalName;
  dynamic? department;
  dynamic? deviceId;
  String? profile;
  String? token;
  String? role;

  factory DoctorResponseLoginModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      DoctorResponseLoginModels(
        doctorId: json["doctorID"],
        nmCno: json["nmCno"],
        doctorName: json["doctorName"],
        contactNo: json["contactNo"],
        username: json["username"],
        emailId: json["emailID"],
        strEmail: json["strEmail"],
        id: json["id"],
        intMobile: json["intMobile"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        currentAddress: json["currentAddress"],
        depId: json["depId"],
        entryDate: json["entryDate"],
        password: json["password"],
        code: json["code"],
        isActive: json["isActive"],
        hospitalName: json["hospitalName"],
        department: json["department"],
        deviceId: json["deviceId"],
        profile: json["profile"],
        token: json["token"],
        role: json["role"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "doctorID": doctorId,
        "nmCno": nmCno,
        "doctorName": doctorName,
        "contactNo": contactNo,
        "username": username,
        "emailID": emailId,
        "strEmail": strEmail,
        "id": id,
        "intMobile": intMobile,
        "gender": gender,
        "currentAddress": currentAddress,
        "depId": depId,
        "entryDate": entryDate,
        "password": password,
        "code": code,
        "isActive": isActive,
        "hospitalName": hospitalName,
        "department": department,
        "deviceId": deviceId,
        "profile": profile,
        "token": token,
        "role": role,
      };
}
```

**And this is where I need it to be displayed, where I have used FutureBuilder and I this I made a mistake here but not sure where exactly.**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 10),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              height: 150.0,
              width: 150.0,
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              child: FutureBuilder<DoctorResponseLoginModels>(
                future: APIService().register(DoctorRequestLoginModels(
                    code: "code", username: "username", password: "password")),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Text('Loading....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        DoctorResponseLoginModels data = snapshot.data!;

                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(data.doctorName!),

                          ],
                        );
                      }
                  }
                },
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: From what i see you can first check if the response is 200 by printing the response.statusCode. and if the response if not 200 so its going in the else block and throwing the exception. Please check if you are passing proper parameters to the api if not 200.

Comment: @SagarAcharya, I did print the response status, it returs 200, I think I made some mistake in FutureBuilder

Comment: ok so can you send me the sample response that you are getting i will check it on my side.

Comment: @SagarAcharya, this is the response I get in my console : {"doctorID":1,"nmCno":"1124","doctorName":"Pradeep Vaidya","contactNo":"9851141119","username":null,"emailID":"pravdya@yahoo.com","strEmail":"pravdya@yahoo.com","id":1,"intMobile":"9851141119","gender":null,"currentAddress":"Maharajgunj, Kathmandu, Bagmati","depId":4,"entryDate":"09-05-2020","password":null,"code":null,"isActive":true,"hospitalName":null,"department":null,"deviceId":null,"profile":"MBBS (Madras Medical College, Madras University, India)","role":"doctor"}

Comment: from what i see this is fine please check if you have internet permissions enabled. And having a proper internet connection. from the code i see when i fetch the data with the dummy json its working fine and parsing properly. not sure why this is occuring as i cannot make the post api call.